# I need to read a list of integers in a csv file, remove the first integer, and find the sum of that list in python

Tags: python

Here's what I have so far

```
import csv
a= []

with open (r"C:\Users\packe\Downloads\transactions.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        b=int(column[0])
        a. append(b)
```

transactions.csv contains these integers[25, 2, 8, -5, 4, 4, 3, 2, -2, 3] 25 being the first integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to sum up all elements of a list except the first one:

```
sum(a_list[1:])
```

If the elements of the list are strings you can do:

```
sum(map(int, a_list[1:]))
```

---

- `a_list[1:]` this is called slicing, have a look [here for an explanation of the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6391362).
- `map(int, a_list)` applies the function `int` (cast to integer) to all elements of `a_list`. [Link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).